# Refactor Select Elements Matching List of Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for some help on how to write some code to reduce redundant code while maintaining clarity.

Given this HTML (vastly simplified from the real thing):

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Day for Code <span class="typeCode">089</span></legend>
        <select name="date1" id="date1" class="dateSelect">
            <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
            <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
            <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Day for Code <span class="typeCode">087</span></legend>
        <select name="date2" id="date2" class="dateSelect">
            <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
            <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
            <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I am wanting to see which days were selected for specific codes. Using jQuery, I could use something like this:

```
$(
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains(061) .dateSelect option:selected," +
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains(064) .dateSelect option:selected," +
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains(065) .dateSelect option:selected", +
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains(089) .dateSelect option:selected," +
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains(090) .dateSelect option:selected"
).each(
    function(index) {
        doSomethingHere();
    }
);
```

However, it seems like there ought to be a way to simplify that selector. Something like this would be nice, but it doesn't seem to be possible:

```
$(
    "div fieldset:has(.typeCode):contains([061,064,065,089,090]) .dateSelect option:selected"
).each(
    function(index) {
        doSomethingHere();
    }
);
```

All I can come up with is something like this:

```
var typeCodes = ["061", "064", "065", "089", "090"];

$("div fieldset:has(.typeCode)").each(
    function(index) {
        var code = $(this).find(".typeCode").text();
        if ($.inArray(code, typeCodes) > -1) {
            var dateSelected = $(this).find(".dateSelect option:selected");
            doSomethingHere();
        }
    }
);
```

That eliminates duplicate code, but at the cost of reduced clarity.

Is there a better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would throw `typecode` on each `fieldset` as a custom `data-*` attribute - `filter` out the ones you don't want - then check the `select`..

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-typecode="089">
    <legend>Select Day for Code <span class="typeCode">089</span></legend>
    <select name="date1" id="date1" class="dateSelect">
        <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

And the JS:

```
var typeCodes = ["061", "064", "065", "089", "090"];

$("fieldset[data-typecode]").filter(function() {
    //Get fieldsets with typecodes in above array and with selected options
    var code = $(this).data("typecode");
    return typeCodes.indexOf(code) > -1 && $(this).find("select option:selected").length
}).each(function() {
    //Do something on each fieldset
});
```